# If $f, g \in L^p$, is it true that $\int | f g | = \int | f | \int | g |$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g \in L^p(0, 1), \;\; 1 < p < \infty$. In this case, is it true that 
$$\underset{(0, 1)}{\int} | f(x) g(x) | dx = \underset{(0, 1)}{\int} | f(x) | dx \underset{(0, 1)}{\int} | g(x) | dx? $$

Why yes/ not?

Thank you!

Comment: no this is not true

Comment: Try to find two non-constant functions for which equality holds.  I think you will find that difficult!

Comment: @GEdgar I was going to ask, is it one of those things with very rare examples? Because to me it looked like almost any counter example functions can be used here even polynomials.

Comment: r.pomegranate should have tried at least one example before asking here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't true. As an example:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if } x\in (0,1/2] \\ 0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$ and

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if } x\in (1/2,1) \\ 0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample: Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and the characteristic functions $\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}$ and $\chi_{(\frac{1}{2},1)}$.  Then $\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}\chi_{(\frac{1}{2},1)} = 0$ but the product of their integrals is $\frac{1}{4}$.